# Have dart class public, but constructor private

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering if there is a way to have a dart class be public, but its contructor be library private. I have a JsonParsing library that will throw its own exception type, but it doesn't make sense for anyone outside of the library to construct this exception.

```
library json_parser;

import 'dart:convert';

class JsonParseException implements Exception {
    final String cause;
    JsonParseException(this.cause); // make this inaccessible in some way?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a private named constructor:

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo._();
}
```